# Advanced usage of indefinite relative pronouns?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

So one of my major grammar stumbling points is a certain usage of *ce que* and *ce qui*. To be clear, I do understand the basic usage of these words and the difference between them, and **every** example on [this page](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/indefiniterelativepronouns.htm) (if you scroll down below the video) is perfectly clear to me, e.g.:

> C'est ce qui me dérange.

Which translates directly to *That's **what** bothers me* in English.

Or:

> Sais-tu ce que Pierre a fait ?

Which again translates directly to *Do you know **what** Pierre did?*

But then you have a sentence like this:

> À qui s'étonnerait de **ce qu'un** gentleman aussi mystérieux comptat parmi les membres de cette honorable association, on répondra qu'il passa sur la recommandation de MM. Baring frères, ches lesquels il avait un crédit ouvert.

In a case like this, the usage does not line up with previous examples. In English, there simply would not be a pronoun there*, which makes it hard for me to understand exactly when it is appropriate to use *ce que* or *ce qui* in a sentence like this.

Generally I am referring to sentences where *ce que* and *ce qui* are preceded by a verb + preposition, just like *s'étonner de*. If I can find other examples I will add them.

*I suppose you can translate *ce que* here to mean *that*, but it's still hard to know when a sentence needs *ce que/qui* used in this manner.

Comment: *jusqu'à ce que* is a related usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first two sentences *que* and *qui* are indeed relative pronouns, and in a literal translation they could be translated with *which*:

> C'est ce qui me dérange. = It is that (thing) **which** bothers me.
>
> Sais-tu ce que Pierre a fait ? = Do you know that (thing) **which** Pierre has done?

But in the third sentence *que* is not a relative pronoun but a **conjunction**, and can't be translated with *which*. So this:

> À qui s'étonnerait de ce qu'un gentleman aussi mystérieux comptât parmi les membres ...

--is best translated as:

> To anyone who would be surprised **that** such a mysterious gentleman was among the members...

Comment: Yes, that is better. I purposely didn't strive for the best translation, but a fairly literal one.